# Representing functions according to ${\cos(n\pi x)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given this S-L:

[image]

I got the Eigenfunctions and Eigenvalues.

now I want to represent $x^2 -1/3$ according to this Eigenfunctions space.

Here is what they did:

[image]

I did the same, But without the `2` outside the integral.. from where did it come? 
note : $B_0 =0$

Comment: "I want to represent $x^2 -1/3$..." over what interval? $[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes, as it comes from S-L interval.. Doesn't it? @RodrigodeAzevedo

Answer (score 0):

The 2 came from normalizing the Eigenfunction